# Deleting a Div on My Blog

Tags: html, shopify

I'm trying to locate/delete this section on blog posts within my blog. I'm just not sure which part to delete/take out or in which liquid file it would exist.

```
<div class="title-box">
        <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase title-under">BLOG</h1>
      </div>
```

Blog post 
https://samplified.us/blogs/tutorials-and-free-downloads/how-to-make-a-beat-like-medasin-tutorial

It just takes up way too much room and doesn't really serve a purpose. I can locate it with inspect tool and delete that div class and it looks perfect.

I'm just not sure where in my theme files I can do that.

When I delete it on google inspector it's exactly how I want it to look. 
[After Deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Njj.png)

[Time Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uOvn.png)

Comment: Admin Login -> Online Store -> Live Theme -> edit code -> Template -> article.liquid file check inside any section included if yes then go that section otherwise code will be on article.liquid

Answer (score 0):

If you use wordpress, usually the css will be on style.css.
You can add display:none to title-box CSS and it will work just fine

Comment: I'm using Shopify :( 
Is there custom code I can add without having to delete?

Comment: Sweet! Got it. Thank you Mr!

Comment: Did you found it? if this work, you can accept it as an answer ^^ Have a nice day~

Comment: I just try to use shopify, you can go to themes->edit code->Assets->theme.scss.liquid and put those code or you can also make new css file and put it inside Assets.

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't work as well. I tried display:none on .post__title_block time. See my 2nd screen shot in the original post.

Comment: remove display:block from .post_title_block time css

Comment: Okay if I remove   display:none; from title.box blog posts do not show up under my blog section. It removes all posts completely from the blog section. I was able to remove the time stamp. Is there a way to edit title-box without affecting the query? (If i'm using the right terminology)

Comment: hmm, you can go to themes->edit code->sections->blog.template.liquid find the title-box and delete it.. Try this way ^^

Answer (score 0):

First, set up a simple dev environment.

- Clone your theme (make sure this theme is not published yet.)
- [Download ThemeKit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/)
- Download your clone theme using ThemeKit. (`theme download`)
- Using ThemeKit watch your changes using the theme preview.

Now try to edit the files and try to figure out what is the best option to delete that div.

- Using your favorite text editor search for the keyword `title-box` and you are going to get all areas where that class is used. You can try to delete it and test out to see if that works for you or not.
- If deleting cause too many problems you can try to hide with CSS.

After you pick your solution and its working on your clone theme (preview mode). You can publish the clone theme over the current live theme.